# Laravel - Named Route + Controller Routing + Parameter Validator not working together

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing

I have a named route using a controller working perfectly. An issue arises when I chain a parameter validator, to ensure the passed question `id` is numeric.

```
Route::get('/question/{id}',
array('as' => 'question_route', 'uses' => 'QuestionsController@showQuestion'))
->where('id',[0-9+]);
```

Laravel throws this exception highlighting the `->where('id',[0-9+]);`

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException
syntax error, unexpected ']'
```

How can all 3 (as, uses, where) work together on a single route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the regex is `[0-9+]` not `[0-9]+`?

And there should be single quotes around it

Comment: Silly mistake on my end, thanks for pointing it out Allen. I also want to add that it should be enclosed it single quotes too - I'll update your answer :)